# Using ASP API identity Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-identity, access-token

I'm creating a message component in my app api and need a way to stop a user from viewing a message they're not apart of. I'm planning on getting their UserId from the token and then checking that against the message's sender and receiver. If they aren't either of those I will not provide the message back to client.

Is this the correct way to set this up or are there better ways for validating things like this?

Comment: afaik it's a good way to validate

Comment: I ended up using Identity's claims system.